# Is this space locally compact?

Tags: general-topology

I think I'm a little confused about the distinction between compact and locally compact:

Let $X,Y$ be Hausdorff spaces. $X$ is locally compact. If $f: X \rightarrow Y$ is continuous,  open, and onto is $Y$ locally compact? Using the definition that every $x \in X$ is contained in a neighborhood whose closure is compact.

It seems that it clearly is: by continuity of $f$ $Y$ is also compact, choose $y \in Y$ and $y \in U \subset Y$ open, take the closure of $U$ and by defition the closure is closed and since $Y$ is compact the closure of $U$ is compact as desired.

I think this proof is wrong because I didn't have to use a lot of the conditions, so it seemed too obvious. Any thoughts?

Comment: Yes, as it stands, the proof is wrong. $Y$ is not necessarily compact, because $X$ isn't.

Comment: I thought local compactness implied compactness?

Comment: No, $\mathbb{R}$ is locally compact, but not compact.

Comment: I stand corrected, okay I'll work on the proof again.

Comment: Thanks, ended up figuring it out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just go back and forth using $f$.    Start with a point $y\in Y$, you want it to be in a neighborhood that's relatively compact, well, the stuff we know about is in $X$.    $f$ is onto, so there exists at least one preimage,   pick one arbitrarilly,   $x\in X, f(x)=y$   Now using the relative compactness of $X$ you get a neighborhood $x\in U$ where the closure of $U$ is compact.   Since $f$ is an open map, $f(U)$ is open,  and $y\in f(U)$.   Morever,  since $f$ is continuous and continuity conserves compactness,  $f(\overline U)$ is compact.  To conclude, all you need to show is that $f(\overline U)=\overline {f(U)}$